# Why is $EX = \int_0^\alpha P[t<X<\alpha]dt + \int_{X\ge \alpha} X dP$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

$EX = \int_0^\alpha P[t<X<\alpha]dt + \int_{X\ge \alpha} X dP.$ This is an identity that comes up in Billingsley's Convergence of Probability measures. However,  I cannot find nor figure out why the expectation of $X$ under $X\le \alpha$ is given by $\int_0^\alpha P[t<X<\alpha]dt.$ Here, $X$ is assumed nonnegative. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the brackets inside the integrals to denote Iverson brackets, then you have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\alpha }\Pr [t<X<\alpha ]\,d t&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}[0\leqslant t<\alpha ] \cdot P[t<X<\alpha ]\,d t\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}[0\leqslant t<\alpha ]\cdot [t<x<\alpha ]F_X(dx)\,d t\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}[0\leqslant t<x<\alpha ]F_X(dx)\otimes dt\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}[0\leqslant x<\alpha ]\cdot [0\leqslant t<x]\,d t\,F_X(dx)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x[0\leqslant x<\alpha ]F_X(dx)\\
&=\int_{[0,\alpha )}x F_X(dx)\\
&=\int_{\{X<\alpha \}}X\,d P
\end{align*}
$$
∎

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^{\alpha} P(t<X<\alpha)dP=\int_0^{\alpha}\int I_{t<x<\alpha}(x)dF(x)dP$ where $F$ is  the distrbution function of $X$. By Fubini's Theorem we get $$\int_0^{\alpha} P(t<X<\alpha)dP$$ $$=\int_{(0,\alpha)}\int_0^{x} dt dF(x)$$ $$=\int_{X<\alpha} xdF(x)$$ $$=EX-\int_{(X\geq \alpha)} xdF(x).$$